# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config' when trying to change a button attribute's font size

Tags: python, tkinter

When trying to use the .config() method to change the font size of the 'button1' attribute of the 'studentmainmenuscreen' object I got this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0osZ.png)

I can't figure out why this error is occurring! Please help me?!

```
class standardclass: #creates the class called 'standardclass'
    def __init__(self, labeltext, b1t, b1c, b2t, b2c, tlxc, b1x, b1y, b2x, b2y): #creates the initalization subroutine and passes the parameters in the bracket
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, highlightthickness=0,  bg='#A9E2f3') #creates the canvas attribute
        self.canvas.pack()  #packs the canvas inside of the root window
        self.titlelabel = Label(self.canvas, text=labeltext, font=('Arial', 30), bg='#A9E2f3').place(x=tlxc,y=20) #creates the title label attribute
        self.button1 = Button(self.canvas, text=b1t, command=b1c, font=('Arial', 30), relief='flat').place(x=b1x,y=b1y) #creates the bottom left button attribute
        self.button2 = Button(self.canvas, text=b2t, command=b2c, font=('Arial', 30), relief='flat').place(x=b2x,y=b2y) #creates the bottom right button attribute

studentmainmenuscreen = standardclass('Main Menu', 'Maths Tests', temporarysubroutine, 'Logout', temporarysubroutine, 225, 200, 300, 200, 400)
studentmainmenuscreen.button1.config(font=('Arial', 20))
studentmainmenuscreen.button1.update()
```

Comment: You are assigning the button to the value returned by `place()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the type of object in line:

```
self.button1 = Button(self.canvas, text=b1t, command=b1c, font=('Arial', 30), relief='flat').place(x=b1x,y=b1y)
```

For both buttons.

You can create the button first, then call the `place()` methods:

```
self.button1 = Button(params)
self.button2 = Button(params)
self.button1.place(params)
self.button2.place(params)
```

Here is a good [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm) to refer to.